# How to make the Open... dialog default to another folder?

Tags: dialog

I have a problem with the old PageSpinner 5.2.1 that has not been updated for a long time and it can no longer remember the last opened folder in Open dialogs and always default to the same ~/Documents folder. Is there a way to change the default folder for a specific application and/or for all applications Open... dialog?

Answer (score 1):

The Open... Dialog defaults to the current folder for MOST applications. You chan change this by [changing directory in Terminal](http://guides.macrumors.com/Terminal) (note that in my experience, some applications, especially Java ones do not follow this default behavior and in stead open the same directory every time, I assume this is hard-coded in the application).

Now to the meat of your question: can we change this behavior on a per-application basis, using the tools OS X has pre-installed?  My guess is yes!, though I don't have time to do the research right now. What we'd be looking for is:

```
# wait for application to be switched 

# see if we have defined a default directory for that app

# if we have change, if not go to default 

# go back to top and wait to app switching
```

Others should definitely feel free to flesh out my skeleton code, please don't accept this answer until it is complete. I'll look again tonight and see if I can't finish that out. [Potentially helpful link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202865)

Comment: I can't reproduce the relationship between the current directory in Terminal and the directory used in the Open dialog, can you clarify where/how exactly this works?

Comment: @patrix, I appear to be wrong, this worked in Mountain Lion, appears to be broken in Yosemite, it looks like it just chooses the last directory selected from an Open... dialogue. I'll look further into it.

Comment: Someone had a similar question on SuperUser, I found a [promising answer](http://superuser.com/a/255907), though that's from back in '11, so I can't vouch for how current it is

Comment: [More](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521151/mac-app-default-working-directory) [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5696757/set-the-default-directory-in-mac-terminal) on where, how, and why this is set. My understanding was that each App was launched from a common shell, hence my current directory method worked. When Apple moved to true sandboxing in OS X 10.9 (or 8?), it was likely changed so that each app launches from its own shell. This is annoying in that it no longer works, but interesting in that there is probably a way to set a default startup directory for each app.

Comment: Applications are started by Finder (kind of), as is Terminal and any shell running within, there isn't (and never was) a relationship between the default directory used by Finder and the one used by Terminal. The linked articles don't really relate to the problem at hand.

Comment: The links were meant to be more informative about where this behavior may be controlled. After playing for bit, it's clear that there is a global "last folder accessed" variable which persists across most apps (Finder obviously excluded). Changing this (using TextEdit or something) is a very possible but hackish way to do what I described in my answer.

Comment: I'm really looking forward to some more details on this, so if you can add some more explanations about this it would be great.

Comment: This has tight grasp on my interest right now - from experimentation, it appears MOST apps have some sort of 'memory' where they will present the last directory you accessed using the Open... dialogue, and this same directory for Save As... . Some apps (OpenOffice) will only remember a directory if you open or save a file there, others (Pages) will remember a directory if you only view it. Note this only holds true for "well-behaved" apps, MATLAB will choose its own startup directory every time, no matter what I do

Comment: To complicate matters, `open -a` commands in terminal do NOT set this 'last used directory', you would need some sort of screen-scraping macro to get the behavior you want without knowing where this 'last used directory' data is held, I guess the first step would be to find out if this is a global daemon keeping track of which apps access what, or if it is stored on a per-app basis in the app's own data.

Comment: [OpenOffice](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=68816) offers the ability to always start the Save As... prompt in a given directory. This is definitely defined in the app though, so it's obvious you could change this from within the app, knowing where or how is a different story.

Comment: $APPNAME/Contents/Info.plst looks promising as a way to handle this (I assume there's some NS call to set a directory NSCoreStorage maybe), I'll definitely come back to this.

Comment: Note: I'm using these comments more as an info dump for me and anyone else interested in this than as an actual forum for discussion. I'll edit my answer and get rid of many of these once a final solution has been worked out.

Comment: [Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204788) has a page about doing something very similar to this, though it's in fairly rough shape right now.

Comment: The linked Apple page talks about switching applications which default to iCloud storage back to local storage, it's *not* about a default directory.

Comment: Correct, the linked article is making the point that this behavior is exposed via NS calls to applications, and that these settings can be modified externally. As iCloud is just mounted as a special kind of local folder, this is definitely externally configurable somehow.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions ... suspected this wasn't very straightforward ... . Earlier old software usually remembered the last opened folder, but that seems to have been lost for some applications that has not been updated. TextEdit for example remembers the last folder accessed still in 10.10.5. Oh well, went through adding some 500 photos changing folder every single time, but would be nice if a user could change this per application basis ad hoc ... (not that Apple is trying to make users interact more with the Finder these days ...).

Comment: Agreed on what a shame the decreased importance placed on Finder is. I'll keep looking into this, updates if anything is found.